# League of Legends login error

Tags: login, games

I installed league of legends on ubuntu 14.04 with play on linux. Everything was OK I played for a month but when once i updated my ubuntu then when i reinstalled LoL and tried to log in it said "Did not revieve response from a server".

I saw a solution when this problem appears on windows. They open internet explorer and it solves the problem. I also installed the IE with play on linux but it did not help.

Sorry for my english and thanks for answers!

[image: Login issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had a similar problem, which was the login server was not responding, I found a solution by doing the following on playonlinux:

- right click on league of legends
- select registry editor
- delete this entry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\DllOverrides

Comment: Tank you! That fixed it for me. However you onyl need to delete the entry wineinet!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. The solution is really simple. Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open terminal. In the opened terminal type: `sudo su`, then type your password (it will not show the password, but the system will catch your characters) and type enter.

In the same terminal, after you have logged in as `root`, copy this:

`echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps` and press enter. Simple.!!